# SSIS - Reading from a multi part text file

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to build an SSIS package that reads from a text file and outputs into another text file.  The catch is that the file I'm trying to read from has multiple sections and I can't find anything that shows how to do that.

The file looks like this:

```
[sectionA]
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3

[sectionB]
key4=value4
key5=value5
key6=value6
```

I started with a couple of tutorials that read from a flat file source but the data gets pulled into an equally ugly table.  Hoping someone has some input on this.

Comment: Do you just need the key values or do you need the section information as well?

Comment: please post your desired output

Comment: Thanks for your replies, my SO notifications are a bit delayed.  I need to pull into a table that reads as:

section name
key1
key2
key3

and then populate those fields with the values.

Answer (score 2):

The SSIS Flat File Connection is built for speed so it doesnt allow for niceties like that.

I would still use the Flat File Connection but just load all the data into a single, wide NVARCHAR column in a SQL table.  I would add an IDENTITY column to that table to get a relative Row Number.

Then I would add downstream tasks using SQL to select by Sections e.g. for Section A rows:

`WHERE File_Row_Number > ( SELECT MIN ( File_Row_Number ) FROM Staging_Table WHERE nvarchar_column = '[sectionA]' )
AND File_Row_Number < ( SELECT MIN ( File_Row_Number ) FROM Staging_Table WHERE nvarchar_column = '[sectionB]' )`

If the split requirements are as simple as those shown I might attempt them in SQL e.g.

[How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

But I would probably lean towards using Strings.Split in a Script Task where the code will be simpler and safer.

Comment: Hi Mike,

That's where I am right now.  I've loaded it all into a single column but I'm using a script task to navigate through the text.

Comment: Took some time, and frustrating the heck out of myself trying to do it in SSIS, but this solution worked perfectly once I understood it.  Thanks Mike!